# differentiation - tangent to the curve $f(x) = (2x-1)(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equations of the tangents to the curve $f(x) = (2x-1)(x+1)$ at the points where the curve cut the x-axis. find the points of intersection of these tangents.

Answer (score 2):

1. Expand the factors of $f(x)$. You can use the product rule to differentiate as is, but it would be simpler to just expand the factors, then differentiate. $$f(x) = (2x - 1)(x+1) = 2x^2 +x - 1$$
2. Find the intercepts the original curve $f(x)$: Solve for the x-values where $f(x) = 0$: there will be two solutions in $x$: $x_1, x_2$. $$\begin{align}f(x) = 0 & \iff (2x - 1)(x + 1) = 0 \\ \\ & \iff 2x - 1 = 0 \;\text{ or } \; x + 1 = 0 \\ \\ &\iff x_1 = \dfrac 12, \;\text{ or }\; x_2 = -1\end{align}$$
3. Find $f'(x)$.

> $$f(x) = 2x^2 + x - 1 \implies f'(x) = 4x + 1$$

1. Then using the solutions from $(2)$, solve $$m_1 = f'(x_1) = f'\left(\frac 12\right),\;\text{ and }\;m_2 = f'(x_2) = f'(-1).\;$$ These are the two slopes, respectively, for the line tangent at $(x_1, 0) = \left(\frac 12, 0\right)$ and the line tangent at $(x_2, 0) = (-1, 0)$.

> $$m_1 = 3,\;\;m_2 = -3.$$

1. Use the point-slope form of an equation to determine the equation of each tangent line. $$y = m_1(x - x_1);\quad y = m_2(x - x_2)$$

> $$y_1 = 3\left(x - \frac 12\right) \iff y_1 = 3x - \frac 32$$ $$y_2 = -3(x -(-1)) = -3(x + 1)\iff y_2 = -3x - 3$$

1. To find the point at which the two tangent lines intersect, set their equations from $(5)$ equal to one another to solve for the $x$-coordinate of the point of intersection. Then use either equation of the lines to solve for the $y$-coordinate of the point of intersection.

> $$y_1 = y_2 \iff 3x - \frac 32 = -3x - 3 \iff 6x = -\frac 32 \iff x = -\frac 14.\;$$ $$x = -\frac 14 \implies y = -\frac 94$$

Comment: Very nice use of spoilers as guidance! The numbers $4 - 6$ are not displaying correctly. +1

Answer (score 0):

To find any line you need two pieces of information: the slope of the line and a point contained in the line.  (Or two points in the line will work.)  The point $(-1,0)$ is one of the intersections of the graph with the $x$-axis.  The slope of the tangent line at that point is $f'(-1)$.  Thus the tangent line (using the point slope formula) at that point is $y-0=f'(-1)(x--1)$.

Similarly for the other $x$-intercept.